# How can keyboard smooth scrolling be turned off in gedit (GNOME 3.14/Fedora 21)?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gedit, scrolling

In gedit on GNOME 3.14 (Fedora 21), using the mousewheel to scroll results in ordinary scrolling, whereas using the arrow keys or PageUp/PageDown results in smooth scrolling. How can smooth scrolling for the arrow keys/PageUp/PageDown be disabled in gedit?